# Can't push directly from Pycharm but can from console (Different author names in pushed commits)

Tags: git, gitlab, pycharm, ssh-keys, wsl-2

I'm facing this strange behavior since my ssh key expired and had to use a new one. I have many projects that I update using git and gitlab as repository, and normally I did that using Pycharm interface, but now it just doesn't work in some of them, so I have to do a manual push from console and it works; but in others pushing from Pycharm works fine. Now, the strange is that commits pushed from Pycharm have my username as an author, and commits pushed from console have my first and last name in it. In git `user.name` is my username, not my full name and I think this is the reason because can't push directly in that projects from Pycharm. How can solve this?
I have only one SSH key in gitlab. I'm using Pycharm 2023.1.4, Windows 10 64bit and WSL2 venvs.